# Ao marcar checkbox, deixar link visível

Tags: javascript, jquery

No meu sistema de gerenciamento de conteúdo, há um checkbox em cada item da lista, seja para editar, excluir, visualizar.. Acontece que esse botão aparece o tempo todo, e caso o usuário não marque nada, ele é praticamente inútil.

Gostaria de que, quando algum checkbox fosse marcado, o botão apareça, e caso haja nenhum marcado, ele desapareça. Ah, se possível, um simples efeito de fadeIn e fadeOut.

> HTML dos checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="deletar[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?> " />
```

> HTML do botão que deve aparecer depois:

```
<input type="submit" class="excluir-varios" value="Excluir selecionados" onClick="return confirm('Deseja realmente deletar os artigos selecionados?')">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basta um pouco de CSS:

```css
.checkshow input[type="submit"] { opacity:0;transition:.5s;pointer-events:none }
.checkshow input:checked ~ input[type="submit"] { opacity:1;pointer-events:auto }
.checkshow input[type="checkbox"] { display:block /*só pra estética do demo */}
```

```html
<div class="checkshow">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="deletar[]" value="1" />   
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="deletar[]" value="2" />   
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="deletar[]" value="3" />   
  <input type="submit" class="excluir-varios" value="Excluir selecionados" onClick="return confirm('Deseja realmente deletar os artigos selecionados?')">
</div>
```

### Pontos de interesse:

```
.checkshow input[type="submit"] { opacity:0;transition:.5s;pointer-events:none }
```

- Aqui definimos opacidade `0` para o botão ficar escondido. Poderiamos
  ter usado `display:none`, mas aí não teriamos animação.
- O `pointer-events:none` desativa o clique no elemento invisível, nos
  `browsers` mais novos.
- O `transition:.5s` prepara a animação, no caso o *fade* do opacity.

```
 .checkshow input:checked ~ input[type="submit"] { opacity:1;pointer-events:auto }
```

- Aqui estamos dizendo "se tiver algum elemento do tipo `submit`, precedido por um elemento `checked`, aplique opacidade `1` e ative o funcionamento do *pointer* do mouse.
- Se tivéssemos vários botões, um por `checked`, usaríamos o `+` no lugar do `~`. O mais significa "elemento imediatamente precedido", ou seja, vincularia cada *checkbox* apenas ao botão que estiver logo em seguida.

Comment: Obrigado, ficou legal. A unica pequena falha do proposto é que, com o opacity, caso o usuário de o azar de clicar no local aonde está o ícone oculto, a mensagem será exibida. Porém, não irá interferir no código, uma vez que não será possível deletar, pois nada foi marcado.

Comment: @ThiagoBarros pode por um display:none, mas aí não dá pra animar com fade. Na verdade eu eliminaria o onclick, e poria algo mais amistoso. Aproveitando, pode verificar se tem algo selecionado, se não tiver, nem aciona. De qq forma, vou melhorar isso.

Comment: Acontece que sou totalmente leigo em jquery e javascript, creio que já deu pra perceber, pois não soube por onde começar com algo tão simples na linguagem. o alert realmente é um pouco incomodo, mas no meu caso servirá para excluir registros do banco de dados, então acredito que por hora sirva. De qualquer forma, obrigado!

Comment: @ThiagoBarros consertei. agora nao clica mais se estiver escondido: `pointer-events:none` desativa, `pointer-events:auto` ativa. Ao menos nos browsers mais novos :) Se precisar pros mais velhos, teria outras técnicas.

Comment: Esse parâmetro é CSS3? nunca tinha lido sobre.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Perfeito @Bacco , obrigado.

Comment: Se no caso tivesse um `input` dentro de uma `td` no exemplo acima iria funcionar ?